# djangocms tutorial installation failure AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'atomic'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've been attempting to install djangocms without success. Details follow

I have the following system:

```
Windows 8.1 64 bit installation
Python 2.7.8
```

You'll see in the djangocms output that I end up using the django version recommeded for the installation:

```
Django version 1.5
```

I've started running through the djangocms tutorial https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Initial%20Setup.md

I've installed a fresh python, pip and virtualenv. I then created the virtualenv, activated it, and used pip from within that virtualenv to install the package

djangocms-installer

I run into an error when I get to the step running

djangocms -p . my_site

During this step, I specify the django version as recommended in the installation.
    Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, stable) [default stable]: 1.5

I really can't make sense of the output. I've read it and searched this group site to the best of my ability, as well as the issue tracker on the tutorial's github site

The output is at the gist link below. Note that I made one small change for this output, I've named the djangocms project mysite rather than my_site. I've achieved the same failure with both

https://gist.github.com/GaryHendrick/107ec2db9dad14928bfd

The error after the initial stack reads

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'atomic'

Have any of you run into this ?

Best Regards,

Gary

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: I've edited above to indicate the Django version. The djangocms executable prompts for a version specification, and the tutorial instructs the user to use 1.5, which I did.

Comment: Issue is django-reversion, which version are you using ? I've gotten this error before, do a pip install django-reversion>=1.7,<1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the tutorial for djangocms changed on August 5th, [you can see the change history here](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/commit/f78c4f94c9217df626dc6705332ba0e1303eece8), and following the changed instructions will prevent this error from arising, but maybe some people will be helped by my experience in the future. I'll explain

The exception which bubbled up out of

```
djangocms -p . my_site
```

was

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'atomic'
```

It turns out that I caused this issue by choosing to run Django 1.5 when prompted here :

```
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, stable) [default stable]:
```

You will see that the following link indicates that the atomic setting is new as of Django version 1.6.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS

I'm not sure of the solution if you are required to use a Django version < 1.6, which is offered as an option above, but if you have the flexibility to use a Django version of 1.6 or greater than you won't run into the exception that I did.